# Pay with google using stripe in android in test mode

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I implemented  pay with google using stripe  in test mode but when iam running app it shows an error .

**error is**

> "unrecognised app.please make sure that you trust this app before
>   proceeding" and it also shows transaction declined : invalid payment

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution. if u know please share your solution

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but see point 4, below, taken from the google pay API documentation. As long as you are in test mode this will show up.

"
public static final int ENVIRONMENT_TEST
Environment constant for running in the test environment with relaxed application / merchant requirements. This environment is suggested for early development and for easily testing the Wallet SDK.

1. Does not require the application to be uploaded to the Google Play
   Store.
2. Does not require a Google Pay Developer Profile.
3. It uses production data, but at the end of the transaction you will
   receive a fake and non chargeable payment credential.

   **4. The user will see a warning message that the app is not
   recognized/verified.**

Constant Value: 3
"

[Google Pay TEST_ENVIORNMENT](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants)